# dataframe get rows between certain value to a certain value in previous row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-munging

I have a dataframe:

```
df = c1 c2 c3 code
     1. 2. 3. 200
     1. 5. 7. 220
     1. 2. 3. 200
     2. 4. 1. 340
     6. 1. 1. 370
     6. 1. 5. 270
     9. 8. 2. 300
     1. 6. 9. 700
     9. 2. 1. 200 
     8. 1. 2  400
     1. 2  1. 200
     2. 5. 3  900
     8. 0. 4. 300
     9. 1. 2. 620
```

I want to take only the rows that are between any row with 300 code to its previous 200 code.
So here I will have

```
df.  c1 c2 c3 code batch_num
     1. 2. 3. 200.   0
     2. 4. 1. 340.   0
     6. 1. 1. 370.   0 
     6. 1. 5. 270.   0
     9. 8. 2. 300.   0
     1. 2  1. 200.   1
     2. 5. 3  900.   1
     8. 0. 4. 300.   1
```

So basically what I need is to:
find each 300, and for each - find the nearest previous 200, and take the rows between them.
It is guaranteed that there will always be at least one 200 before each 300.
Than, add a columns that indicate the proper batch.
How can I do it efficiently in pandas?

Comment: It working well, I see. Performance is better of rolling?

Comment: @jezrael both are good but I think the second answer might be more readable ?

Comment: I think my answer was accepting because faster ;) Because rolling is obviously slow.

Comment: testing small sample data - `2.39 ms` rolling solution, `2.09 ms my solution`, what is performance in real data?

Comment: 0.3 ms is negligible and rolling is more flexible if you want to select an arbitrary number of rows before/after, but let me update to be faster for n = 1

Comment: I think in small data sample no problem, so I ask for real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# rows after 200 are True
m1 = df['code'].map({200: True, 300: False}).ffill()
# rows before 300 are True
m2 = df['code'].map({300: True, 200: False}).bfill()

# if both conditions True, expand to ± 1
m = (m1&m2).rolling(3, min_periods=1, center=True).max().astype(bool)

# select
out = df[m]

# add batch
out['batch_num'] = out['code'].eq(200).cumsum().sub(1)
```

output:

```
     c1   c2   c3  code  batch_num
2   1.0  2.0  3.0   200          0
3   2.0  4.0  1.0   340          0
4   9.0  8.0  2.0   300          0
8   1.0  2.0  1.0   200          1
9   2.0  5.0  3.0   900          1
10  8.0  0.0  4.0   300          1
```

Intermediates:

```
     c1   c2   c3  code     m1     m2  m1&m2  rolling_max
0   1.0  2.0  3.0   200   True  False  False        False
1   1.0  5.0  7.0   220   True  False  False        False
2   1.0  2.0  3.0   200   True  False  False         True
3   2.0  4.0  1.0   340   True   True   True         True
4   9.0  8.0  2.0   300  False   True  False         True
5   1.0  6.0  9.0   700  False  False  False        False
6   9.0  2.0  1.0   200   True  False  False        False
7   8.0  1.0  2.0   400   True  False  False        False
8   1.0  2.0  1.0   200   True  False  False         True
9   2.0  5.0  3.0   900   True   True   True         True
10  8.0  0.0  4.0   300  False   True  False         True
11  9.0  1.0  2.0   620  False    NaN  False        False
```

##### faster approach without rolling if only one row before/after is needed:

```
m = m1&m2
m = m|m.shift()|m.shift(-1)

out = df[m]
out['batch_num'] = out['code'].eq(200).cumsum().sub(1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry but pls see minor edit (add batch column)

Comment: Use `out['batch'] = out['code'].eq(200).cumsum().sub(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Idea is filter only rows matched both values by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
#create default index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

v = [200, 300]

df1 = df[df['code'].isin(v)]
```

Then get all indices with consecutive 200, 300 pairs (by list):

```
m1 = df1['code'].eq(v[0]) & df1['code'].shift(-1).eq(v[1])
m2 = df1['code'].eq(v[1]) & df1['code'].shift().eq(v[0])

idx = df1.index[m1 | m2]

print (df1[m1 | m2])
     c1   c2   c3  code
2   1.0  2.0  3.0   200
6   9.0  8.0  2.0   300
10  1.0  2.0  1.0   200
12  8.0  0.0  4.0   300
```

Last add missing indices between pairs and select original DataFrame and `batch_num` column by compare by first value `200` with cumulative sum, last subtract `1`:

```
df2 = df.loc[[x for a, b in zip(idx[::2],idx[1::2]) for x in range(a, b + 1)]]

df2['batch_num'] = df2['code'].eq(v[0]).cumsum().sub(1)
print (df2)
     c1   c2   c3  code  batch_num
2   1.0  2.0  3.0   200          0
3   2.0  4.0  1.0   340          0
4   6.0  1.0  1.0   370          0
5   6.0  1.0  5.0   270          0
6   9.0  8.0  2.0   300          0
10  1.0  2.0  1.0   200          1
11  2.0  5.0  3.0   900          1
12  8.0  0.0  4.0   300          1
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry but pls see minor edit (add batch column)

Comment: @okuoub - aded to answer - processing new data and new column.